# Could not includ java library(.jar) in java based web service or Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc, mysql-connector

I am new to java based web service. I am able to create web service in java. I am made connection using ODBC connection to MySQL. I want to make connection using JDBC connection.

For that I included jar file (`mysqlconnector.jar`) in `Build Path` of project in Eclipse.

The problem is that it throws a `ClassNotFoundException` at the line where I used class of that jar file.

```
String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName";
        String USER = "root";
        String PASSWORD = "abc@123";
        String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";// driver from the jar file
Class.forName(DRIVER);//gives exception here
con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);//return null here
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The required API also required at runtime, put it into `WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: is there any short cut for putting that jar file into WEB-INF/lib manually.

Comment: instruct your build tool to do it

Comment: Simply put jar file into your WEB-INF/lib if you don't want to go for buuld tool way